# Should I use enums or class hierarchy for errors in swift?

Tags: swift, enums

In Swift 2 any type that conforms to ErrorType protocol can be thrown and caught. For me, it makes sense to have a common error hierarchy and re-use it in multiple places. But, Apple documentation seems to push developers into using enums for handling errors.

For example, this hierarchy will let me catch and process a common ValidationError without knowing it's exact sub-type. This will also allow different parts of the application to extend ValidationError.

```
MyAppError
    ValidationError
        InvalidPathError
        WrongFileTypeError
```

Mixing different styles of defining errors does not look like a good idea. So, should I model all error handling around class hierarchies or enums?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Enums work, classes work. What do you want to know?

Comment: I think the question is answerable, there are clear advantages and disadvantages to using enums vs. classes.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

Enums are shorter, faster to write, easier to understand the potential errors, and the compiler will make sure you catch all of the errors.

### The full story

`ErrorType` itself is just a empty protocol (there are hidden properties `_code : Int` and `_domain : String` but Apple takes care of that).

I quote from The Swift Programming Guide [(link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

> Swift enumerations are particularly well suited to modeling a group of
>   related error conditions, with associated values allowing for
>   additional information about the nature of an error to be
>   communicated.

To elaborate on that, enums allow you to express what exactly can go wrong. When doing error handling, you generally will have specific conditions that can fail (Swift pushes you in this direction with optionals and type safety).
Because errors are distinct cases you shouldn't really need many layers of inheritance (If you do add details to your answer please). Errors can be represented easily with enums. Using a large inheritance hierarchy is overly complicated.

Say you want every error to have a message that can be displayed to the user. Instead of a subclass you could just use a protocol.

```
protocol MyAppError : ErrorType {
    var message: String { get }
}
```

Taking your given example a little further you would represent your `ValidationError` as an enum (as there are many validation errors).

```
enum ValidationError : MyAppError {
    case InvalidPathError (String)
    case WrongFileTypeError (expectedFileType: String)

    var message: String {
        switch self {
        case .InvalidPathError(let invalidPath):
            return "\(invalidPath) is an invalid path"
        case .WrongFileTypeError(let expectedFileType):
            return "Expected type of \(expectedFileType)"
        }
    }
}
```

_

```
func myFileFunction(path: String) throws {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: path) else {
        throw ValidationError.InvalidPathError(path)
    }
    guard let data = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url) else {
        throw ValidationError.WrongFileTypeError(expectedFileType: ".plist")
    }
    print(data)
}


do {
    try myFileFunction("hi.jpg")
} catch ValidationError.InvalidPathError(let path) {
    print("Darn, had a bad path \(path)")
} catch ValidationError.WrongFileTypeError(let expectedType) {
    print("Darn, expected the type \(expectedType)")
}  catch (let error as MyAppError) {
    print("Darn, some old error \(error.message)")
}
```

The compiler actually knows that the function will only throw ValidationErrors so it warns you if you try and catch `MyAppError`. Here a another/better way to do it.

```
do {
    try myFileFunction("hi.jpg")
} catch (let error as ValidationError) {
    switch error {
    case .WrongFileTypeError(let expectedType):
        print("Darn, expected the type \(expectedType)")
    case .InvalidPathError(let path):
        print("Darn, had a bad path \(path)")
    }
}
```

Lets compare to the OO class/inheritance

```
class MyAppError : CustomStringConvertible {
    let message: String

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

    var description: String {
        return message
    }
}

class ValidationError : MyAppError {

}

class InvalidPathError : ValidationError {
    let path: String

    init(message: String, path: String) {
        self.path = path
        super.init(message: message)
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "\(path) is an invalid path"
    }
}

class WrongFileTypeError : ValidationError {
    let expectedFileType: String

    init(message: String, expectedFileType: String) {
        self.expectedFileType = expectedFileType
        super.init(message: message)
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "Expected type of \(expectedFileType)"
    }
}
```

_

```
func myFileFunction(path: String) throws {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: path) else {
        throw InvalidPathError(path: path)
    }
    guard let data = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url) else {
        throw WrongFileTypeError(expectedFileType: ".plist")
    }
    print(data)
}

do {
    try myFileFunction("hi.jpg")
} catch (let error as InvalidPathError) {
    print("Darn, had a bad path \(error.path)")
} catch (let error as WrongFileTypeError) {
    print("Darn, expected the type \(error.expectedFileType)")
} catch (let error as MyAppError) {
    print("Some other error")
}
```

As you can see, it works but creating the error classes adds a lot of baggage. We also don't get the automatic namespacing from `ValidationError.WrongFileTypeError` or `let error as ValidationError`. All someone reading this class knows is that `InvalidPathError` and `WrongFileTypeError` are specifically caught. Contrast that to the enum version where you know `ValidationError` instances are being caught and THE COMPILER tells you this.

Comment: "ErrorType itself is just a empty protocol" No it isn't. It looks empty in the header but in fact it requires a `_domain` property and a `_code` property.

Comment: I'm aware of that but they are hidden and are meant to be private. But I see what you mean and i'll clarify that